# Access working when it shouldn't

Tags: php, symfony

My access control doesn't work. When I'm anonymous, I can access to the url `/admin`, or normally it's must be impossible.

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username 

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: liste_projet
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            login_path: /
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    ~

access_control:
     - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/inscription, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Do you have an idea? A bad configuration of me? I'm using symfony3

Comment: Please, avoid *doesn't work* statements and try to be more specific about your expected result and what you really are getting, like an error, incorrect result, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

to

```
 - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Otherwise when you request the `/admin` page, the path won't match with the first one.